# Android - Get hidden input value of html page using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, html, regex, session, hidden

[I already asked a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468852/android-regex-pattern-for-hidden-html-input-fields-value), but wasn't providing enough details. So here is the "same" question, but this time more in-depth.

I've got a webpage with html, and somewhere on that page I have: `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="the_value_I_want" />`

So, my question is: How can I get the value (the_value_I_want) of the `hidden text field` in Android, **using HttpGet of an already open DefaultHttpClient connection**?

My current code:

```
// Method to get the hidden-input value of the Token
private String getToken(){
    String url = "http://myhost/Account/Login";
    String hidden_token = "";
    String response = "";

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    try{
        // Send the GET-request
        HttpResponse execute = MainActivity.HttpClient.execute(get);

        // Get the response of the GET-request
        InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String s = "";
        while((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
            response += s;

        content.close();
        buffer.close();

        // Get the value of the hidden input-field with the name __RequestVerificationToken
        // TODO
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return hidden_token;
}
```

So, what should I add on the TODO-line?

Because the `Token` and `Cookie` only remain as long as the `Session` stays open, I can't use the `Jsoup library` for finding the hidden field (which I did by using the code below). Instead I need to use the already open `DefaultHttpClient`.

Jsoup code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); // <- this opens a new session
org.jsoup.nodes.Element el = doc.select("input[name*=" + TOKEN).first();
hidden_token = el.attr("value");
```

Thanks in advance for the responses.

PS: For those wondering: I need this token to be able to Log-in using a Google-account with a `POST-request`, combined with the `token` I got from a `Cookie`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lucky for me this was very simple. I just replaced `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();` with `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);`

So in the code of the main post I replaced `//TODO` with:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
org.jsoup.nodes.Element el = doc.select("input[name*=" + TOKEN).first();
hidden_token = el.attr("value");
```

---

Edit 1:

I thought this did the trick, but it doesn't.. It still thinks there are two different `Sessions` opened.. :S

Does `Jsoup.parse(...)` open a new `Jsoup.get-session` behind the scenes?

---

Edit 2:

It's even worse.. Every time another page is opened on the website, another session is created and therefore another token is needed.. So I need to discuss some things with the creator of the website/web api hybrid and figure some things out.. Perhaps create a different log-in just for the Web API..

All in all I'm kinda frustrated right now, even though all the problems I've encountered are "solved"..